How to force gcc to do printf checks on non-literal format strings?
const char* const non_literal_string = "Hello %d";

void my_print()
{
    /* 
     * I would like GCC to throw a warning when compiling this line because the
     * argument is not of int type.
     */
    printf(non_literal_string, "World!");
    
    //Like it does here
    printf("Hello %d", "World!");
}

Above I have declared non_literal_string as const char* const so neither the pointer nor the pointed string can change, so there are the conditions for which GCC can check that the supplied arguments have types appropriate to the specified format string.
With clang compiler these checks are performed even on non-literal format strings, this is the output if I try to compile this code with clang:
<source>:11:32: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'char *' [-Wformat]
   11 |     printf(non_literal_string, "World!");
      |            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^~~~~~~~
<source>:3:47: note: format string is defined here
    3 | const char* const non_literal_string = "Hello %d";
      |                                               ^~
      |                                               %s
<source>:14:24: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'char *' [-Wformat]
   14 |     printf("Hello %d", "World!");
      |                   ~~   ^~~~~~~~
      |                   %s


You would probably have to propose the feature for GCC.  Since it's not there, continue using both Clang and GCC — they have different error messages.  If it compiles cleanly on both, you're reasonably safe.   If you've not yet compiled with both compilers, you can have mistakes which one compiler diagnoses and the other does not.  Until you've compiled with both, you may be missing some safeguards.

You can't "force" a compiler to perform a check it doesn't know how to do. If GCC could do this check, I'm pretty sure it would do so by default.

@Parminder Singh,  Instead of const char* const non_literal_string = "Hello %d";, code could use #define MY_PRINT_FMT "Hello %d"  ... intf(MY_PRINT_FMT, "World!");.  Why do you need a non_literal_string instead of a string literal?

@Barmar GCC have all the information to do that check, indeed clang compiler does these checks by default.

@ParminderSingh technically you pass reference to the string literal.

@0___________ Sorry, I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

non_literal_string holds address of the string literal. So you pass the reference to the string literal to printf.

@0___________ Thanks for the clarification, but I don't understand why passing a reference to a string literal is an impediment for GCC to check that the supplied arguments have types appropriate to the specified format string.

Of course the information is there, since clang does it. It's just not programmed to do this -- someone has to code that check. Since it's open source, so if you think it should be easy, go ahead and add it.

@Barmar I don't know if it's easy or not, in any case it wouldn't be easy for me, I would have to study how compilers work, which could easily take me years, but I think it's probably easier for those who have developed GCC or for those who know how it works internally.

@chux-ReinstateMonica Basically because this way I can use non_literal_string in more parts of the code without increasing the code size (executable binary), which would happen if I used a #define.

@Parminder Singh Are you certain about increasing the code size - was it measured?  Good compilers will use the same string literal and not increase size.  If, in fact, your size increases, Perhaps you would be more productive with a better compiler or enabling such options.

@chux-ReinstateMonica I'm working on a project that will be used on different platforms (even very different from each other) and different compiler types (even quite old ones), so I don't want to leave this optimization freedom to the compiler, but make it possible through the way I write the code.

@ParminderSingh So the without increasing the code size is not something you have tested and reported. (The approach posted above is expected to increase code size with some compilers as it employs both a string literal and a pointer and decreases a compilers ability to optimize.) I'd expect any real space savings to be minor and not an effective use of yours (and others') time in trying to reduce code footprint.  A better approach would post a [mcve] and ask how to reduce footprint.

@chux-ReinstateMonica Here I tried to compile some code with a random compiler and I noticed that it increase the code size by repeating the same literal-string, compiled with the /Ot option, which is the default setting which tells the compiler to favor optimizations for speed over optimizations for size. https://godbolt.org/z/4G9bez9az

Poor man's static analyzer = run the finished code through multiple compilers with max warnings enabled. That's a pretty good trick to catch all manner of problems.

Bottom line, this question is about a tool, that does not do what you want. There is no "forcing". You can go and fix the tool and contribute to gcc. You can make a feature or bug request to gcc bugzilla. GCC have all the information to do that check while true, is not really an argument. Yes, compiler has all the information, it can precalculate all the values. It is a quality of the implementation issue, the quality is what it is. That something is possible, doesn't imply that it is happening, if is not happening, you can implement it.

increasing the code size but if non_literal_string is extern, the value will not be visible to other translation units, so gcc nor clang will error. The only way I see non_literal_string used that it is static and is either defined in a header file, in which case you depend on the merging of literal strings between translation units anyway, or you are using it within a single translation unit only so that compiler can emit the warning and optimize to single memory. It's just simpler to make it a macro. Also, it is optimizing for ~10 bytes, we have terabytes machines now.

@KamilCuk it is optimizing for ~10 bytes, we have terabytes machines now - Yes, nowadays machines have TB of memory, but there are still machines that have a few KB of memory (and I'm working on a project where the platforms think in KB and not terabytes).

this way I can use non_literal_string in more parts of the code without increasing the code size all optimizing compilers can optimize duplicated strings

@phuclv all - is a pretty strong term, it means that you have analyzed and know all the existing compilers. In one of the comments above I posted a link to a compiler that doesn't do this kind of optimization.

@KamilCuk if non_literal_string is extern, the value will not be visible to other translation units, so gcc nor clang will error - Not true, I can declare non_literal_string as extern (in header file without initializing it), define my_print() as inline (in header file) without the storage-class-specifier, define non_literal_string in the source file, declare my_print() as extern in the source file,  #include the header file at the end of the source file, in this way the compiler know the value of non_literal_string at compile time. See https://godbolt.org/z/z8qPfxx9P

Hi @ParminderSingh  Other translation units is crucial. It is visible in the same translation unit temp.c where it is defined, which is where from the warning is generated temp.c:1:54: note:. temp.c is where it is defined. It is not visible in main.c, for example.

@KamilCuk What's the problem if it is not visible in main.c? I'm not going to use non_literal_string in different translation unit, I'm using only my_print().

@KamilCuk My ultimate goal was to have inlineable functions without literal-strings being repeated (cloned) around in different translation units and at the same time get warnings from the compiler when the arguments doesn't match the format string.


How to force gcc to do printf checks on non-literal format strings?

A program does not do something that you would want the program to do. The only possible way to "force" gcc to do anything is to change it. You can modify gcc source code to do the check and implement it. You could post it as a bug or feature request to gcc bugzilla and also fund gcc development https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GNUToolchainFund .
The feature is just not implemented, it's not there. There is no "forcing".

With "force" I meant if there was an option/flag that allowed these checks to be enabled, I guess I shouldn't have used the term "force".

Then I believe the answer is "there is no such option". If there is, someone will come and post an answer and prove me wrong ;)
